# Как данные которые введены первом окне, отобразить во втором?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, сигналы-слоты, qstackedlayout

Помогите разобраться у меня есть стек окон, я хочу чтобы возраст,  который я ввожу в первом и жму далее, отобразился во втором окне:

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QPushButton, QStackedLayout, QVBoxLayout, QApplication
from ghhggh import WindowCalculatorKbju
from fffhhgh import WindowCalculatorResult
import sys


class TextEditDemo(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TextEditDemo, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Пример QStackedLayout")
        self.resize(400, 800)
        self.setStyleSheet('background-color: #bbe3ad;')

        self.form1 = WindowCalculatorKbju()
        self.form2 = WindowCalculatorResult()

        widget = QWidget()
        self.stacked_layout = QStackedLayout()
        widget.setLayout(self.stacked_layout)
        widget.setStyleSheet('background-color: #bbe3ad;')
        self.stacked_layout.addWidget(self.form1)
        self.stacked_layout.addWidget(self.form2)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(widget)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.form1.btn_calculate_calculator.clicked.connect(self.btnPress2_Clicked)
        self.form2.btn_test.clicked.connect(self.btnPress1_Clicked)


    def btnPress1_Clicked(self):
        self.stacked_layout.setCurrentIndex(0)

    def btnPress2_Clicked(self):
        self.stacked_layout.setCurrentIndex(1)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = TextEditDemo()

    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**ghhggh.py**:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QApplication, QPushButton, QFrame, QCheckBox, QRadioButton, QGroupBox,
                             QLabel, QComboBox)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIntValidator, QDoubleValidator
from PyQt5.Qt import *
import sys


class WindowCalculatorKbju(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(WindowCalculatorKbju, self).__init__()

        self.resize(400, 800)

        self.fram = QFrame()
        self.fram.setFixedSize(300, 600)
        self.fram.setFrameStyle(QFrame.Box)
        self.fram.setStyleSheet('''QFrame {
                        background-color: #83cd6e;
                        border-radius: 30px;
        }''')
        shadow = QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(blurRadius=70, xOffset=-15, yOffset=15, color=QColor('#83cd6e'))
        self.fram.setGraphicsEffect(shadow)


        self.label_age = QLabel('Введите возраст:')
        self.label_age.setStyleSheet('''QLabel{
                        font-size: 14px;
                        color: #ffffff;
                        font-weight: bold;
        }''')

        self.input_age = QLineEdit()
        self.input_age.setValidator(QIntValidator(1, 10))
        self.input_age.setPlaceholderText('0')
        self.input_age.setFixedSize(50, 20)
        self.input_age.setStyleSheet('''QLineEdit{
                        background-color: #efefef;
                        border-radius: 2px;
                        border: none;
                        border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
                        color: #000000;
                        font-size: 16px;
                        font-weight: bold;
        }''')



        self.btn_calculate_calculator = QPushButton('Рассчитать')
        self.btn_calculate_calculator.setFixedSize(280, 45)
        self.btn_calculate_calculator.setStyleSheet('''QPushButton{
                                border: 2px solid #ffffff;
                                font-size: 16px;
                                font-weight: bold;
                                background-color: #83cd6e;
                                border-radius: 15px;
                                color: #ffffff;
                                font-weight: bold;

        }
        QPushButton:pressed {
                                background-color: #ffd09d;
        }''')



        #  Бокс возраст
        age_box = QHBoxLayout()
        age_box.setSpacing(8)
        age_box.addWidget(self.label_age)
        age_box.addWidget(self.input_age)
        age_box.addStretch(1)





        self.fram_box = QVBoxLayout()
        self.fram_box.setContentsMargins(10, 50, 10, 0)
        self.fram_box.setSpacing(40)

        self.fram_box.insertLayout(0, age_box)

        self.fram_box.insertWidget(1, self.btn_calculate_calculator, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.fram_box.insertStretch(7, 1)

        self.fram.setLayout(self.fram_box)

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(self.fram, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setLayout(main_layout)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = WindowCalculatorKbju()

    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**fffhhgh.py**:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QApplication, QPushButton, QFrame, QLabel, QVBoxLayout,
                             QGraphicsDropShadowEffect, QHBoxLayout)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from ghhggh import WindowCalculatorKbju

import sys



class WindowCalculatorResult(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(WindowCalculatorResult, self).__init__()

        self.resize(400, 800)



        self.fram = QFrame()
        self.fram.setFixedSize(300, 600)
        self.fram.setFrameStyle(QFrame.Box)
        self.fram.setStyleSheet('''QFrame {
                        background-color: #83cd6e;
                        border-radius: 30px;
        }''')
        shadow = QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(blurRadius=70, xOffset=-15, yOffset=15, color=QColor('#83cd6e'))
        self.fram.setGraphicsEffect(shadow)

        self.label = QLabel(f'Ваш возраст:')

        self.btn_test = QPushButton('назад')
        self.btn_test.setFixedSize(280, 45)
        self.btn_test.setStyleSheet('''QPushButton{
                                        border: 2px solid #ffffff;
                                        font-size: 16px;
                                        font-weight: bold;
                                        background-color: #83cd6e;
                                        border-radius: 15px;
                                        color: #ffffff;
                                        font-weight: bold;

                }
                QPushButton:pressed {
                                        background-color: #ffd09d;
                }''')

        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addWidget(self.label)

        self.fram_box = QVBoxLayout()
        self.fram_box.setContentsMargins(10, 50, 10, 0)
        self.fram_box.setSpacing(40)
        self.fram_box.insertLayout(0, hbox)
        self.fram_box.insertWidget(1, self.btn_test)

        self.fram_box.insertStretch(7, 1)

        self.fram.setLayout(self.fram_box)

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(self.fram, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setLayout(main_layout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = WindowCalculatorResult()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в начале метода `btnPress2_Clicked()` строку:

```
def btnPress2_Clicked(self):
    # +++   
    self.form2.label.setText(
        f'Ваш возраст: <b style="color: red; font-size: 22px;">'
        f'{self.form1.input_age.text()}</b>'
    )
    
    self.stacked_layout.setCurrentIndex(1)
```

---

**q1370772_main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QPushButton, QStackedLayout, \
    QVBoxLayout, QApplication
    
from q1370772_ghhggh import WindowCalculatorKbju
from q1370772_fffhhgh import WindowCalculatorResult


class TextEditDemo(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TextEditDemo, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Пример QStackedLayout")
        self.resize(400, 800)
        self.setStyleSheet('background-color: #bbe3ad;')

        self.form1 = WindowCalculatorKbju()  
        self.form2 = WindowCalculatorResult()       

        widget = QWidget()
        self.stacked_layout = QStackedLayout()
        widget.setLayout(self.stacked_layout)
        widget.setStyleSheet('background-color: #bbe3ad;')
        self.stacked_layout.addWidget(self.form1)
        self.stacked_layout.addWidget(self.form2)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(widget)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.form1.btn_calculate_calculator.clicked.connect(self.btnPress2_Clicked)
        self.form2.btn_test.clicked.connect(self.btnPress1_Clicked)

    def btnPress1_Clicked(self):
        self.stacked_layout.setCurrentIndex(0)

    def btnPress2_Clicked(self):
        # +++   
        self.form2.label.setText(
            f'Ваш возраст: <b style="color: red; font-size: 22px;">'
            f'{self.form1.input_age.text()}</b>'
        )
        
        self.stacked_layout.setCurrentIndex(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = TextEditDemo()

    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**q1370772_ghhggh.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class WindowCalculatorKbju(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):       
        super(WindowCalculatorKbju, self).__init__()

        self.resize(400, 800)

        self.fram = QFrame()
        self.fram.setFixedSize(300, 600)
        self.fram.setFrameStyle(QFrame.Box)
        self.fram.setStyleSheet('''
            QFrame {
                background-color: #83cd6e;
                border-radius: 30px;
            }
        ''')
        shadow = QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(
            blurRadius=70, 
            xOffset=-15, 
            yOffset=15, 
            color=QColor('#83cd6e')
        )
        self.fram.setGraphicsEffect(shadow)


        self.label_age = QLabel('Введите возраст:')
        self.label_age.setStyleSheet('''
            QLabel {
                font-size: 14px;
                color: #ffffff;
                font-weight: bold;
            }
        ''')

        self.input_age = QLineEdit()
        self.input_age.setValidator(QIntValidator(1, 10))
        self.input_age.setPlaceholderText('0')
        self.input_age.setFixedSize(50, 20)
        self.input_age.setStyleSheet('''
            QLineEdit {
                background-color: #efefef;
                border-radius: 2px;
                border: none;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
                color: #000000;
                font-size: 16px;
                font-weight: bold;
            }
        ''')

        self.btn_calculate_calculator = QPushButton('Рассчитать')
        self.btn_calculate_calculator.setFixedSize(280, 45)
        self.btn_calculate_calculator.setStyleSheet('''
            QPushButton {
                border: 2px solid #ffffff;
                font-size: 16px;
                font-weight: bold;
                background-color: #83cd6e;
                border-radius: 15px;
                color: #ffffff;
                font-weight: bold;
            }
            QPushButton:pressed {
                background-color: #ffd09d;
            }
        ''')

        #  Бокс возраст
        age_box = QHBoxLayout()
        age_box.setSpacing(8)
        age_box.addWidget(self.label_age)
        age_box.addWidget(self.input_age)
        age_box.addStretch(1)

        self.fram_box = QVBoxLayout()
        self.fram_box.setContentsMargins(10, 50, 10, 0)
        self.fram_box.setSpacing(40)

        self.fram_box.insertLayout(0, age_box)

        self.fram_box.insertWidget(
            1, 
            self.btn_calculate_calculator, 
            alignment=Qt.AlignCenter
        )
        self.fram_box.insertStretch(7, 1)
        self.fram.setLayout(self.fram_box)

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(self.fram, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setLayout(main_layout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = WindowCalculatorKbju()

    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**q1370772_fffhhgh.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *
# ??? from ghhggh import WindowCalculatorKbju


class WindowCalculatorResult(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(WindowCalculatorResult, self).__init__()
        self.resize(400, 800)

        self.fram = QFrame()
        self.fram.setFixedSize(300, 600)
        self.fram.setFrameStyle(QFrame.Box)
        self.fram.setStyleSheet('''QFrame {
                        background-color: #83cd6e;
                        border-radius: 30px;
        }''')
        shadow = QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(
            blurRadius=70, xOffset=-15, yOffset=15, 
            color=QColor('#83cd6e'))
        self.fram.setGraphicsEffect(shadow)

        self.label = QLabel(f'Ваш возраст:')

        self.btn_test = QPushButton('назад')
        self.btn_test.setFixedSize(280, 45)
        self.btn_test.setStyleSheet('''QPushButton{
                                        border: 2px solid #ffffff;
                                        font-size: 16px;
                                        font-weight: bold;
                                        background-color: #83cd6e;
                                        border-radius: 15px;
                                        color: #ffffff;
                                        font-weight: bold;
                }
                QPushButton:pressed {
                    background-color: #ffd09d;
                }''')

        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addWidget(self.label)

        self.fram_box = QVBoxLayout()
        self.fram_box.setContentsMargins(10, 50, 10, 0)
        self.fram_box.setSpacing(40)
        self.fram_box.insertLayout(0, hbox)
        self.fram_box.insertWidget(1, self.btn_test)
        self.fram_box.insertStretch(7, 1)
        self.fram.setLayout(self.fram_box)

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(self.fram, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setLayout(main_layout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = WindowCalculatorResult()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, отметил!

Comment: @Tesla пожалуйста.